# ES6 Arrow Function with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Extremely new to Typescript,
I'm not sure how to make this work.

Did some research like destructuring but still am not able to get it right.

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
};

const App = (style: any): {} => {
  const { container } = styles;
  return (
    <View style={container}>
      <Text>Open up App.tsx to start working on your app!</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Error below:

```
(JSX attribute) style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>
Type '{ flex: number; backgroundColor: string; alignItems: string; justifyContent: string; }' is not assignable to type 'StyleProp<ViewStyle>'.
  Type '{ flex: number; backgroundColor: string; alignItems: string; justifyContent: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ViewStyle'.
    Types of property 'alignItems' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'FlexAlignType'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(2206, 5): The expected type comes from property 'style' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<View> & Readonly<ViewProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'
```

Comment: Just added the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify type of "container" explicitly. There is generic `ViewStyle` type you can use from `react-native` package:

```js
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ViewStyle } from "react-native";

const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  } as ViewStyle
};

const App = () => {
  const { container } = styles;
  return (
    <View style={container}>
      <Text>Open up App.tsx to start working on your app!</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: need to get more used to `ViewStyles` and other RN out-of-the-box things, but this worked. Thank you.

Comment: Actually it is type inference issue of TypeScript. It infers that type of "alignItems" is "string" but React expects string literal type. You can check for more details here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9336

Comment: I have a few concerns about this answer. 1. A parameter by the name of style is accepted by App, but actually it isn't used at all (styles which is a local variable is used). 2. The return of App is typed as an empty object. Actually the return type is ReactNode. I suspect the current implementation doesn't work with Typescript.

Comment: @BenCarp You are right, I just showed how to fix problem author is having, but did not address some of the issues. It would still work in Typescript though. I made an edit to fix those.

Answer (score 1):

```
const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
};

const App: React.SFC = () => {
   return 
      <View style={styles.container}>
         <Text>Open up App.tsx to start working on your app!</Text>
      </View>
   )
}
```

- React doesn't support Typescript by default, so make sure you have @typescript/react installed in you package.json

Comment: `@types/react` and `@typescript/react`, are they the same thing?

Comment: @types/react adds all the typescript type definition for React's API. For example - React.FC (Functional component),

Comment: I think it should work as well, I will need to learn more about this. Thank you very much Ben for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the type of your styles variable

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

type Style = {
  [key: string]: Object;
};

type ViewStyles = {
  container: Style;
};

const styles: ViewStyles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
};

const App: React.SFC = () => {
  const { container }: Style = styles;
  return (
    <View style={container}>
      <Text>Open up App.tsx to start working on your app!</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Does not this make everything untyped?

Comment: how's that ? everything untyped ?

Comment: container will be of type `Object` which is basically object with any properties

Comment: of course you can add another type to type that but inside there is CSS properties  you gonna write them all ?

Comment: Specify proper type like `ViewStyle` for example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197746/discussion-between-g-aziz-and-aleksey).